# Trying to set AUTHBIND=yes, but file etc/default/tomcat8 not created when installing tomcat from zip file

Tags: apache, ubuntu, server, tomcat8, port80

Hi so basically what I am trying to do is get my spring web-application to run on port 80. I have installed tomcat8 and apache on a Ubuntu server and everything is running smoothly on myDomainName.com:8080, I have tried installing Authbind to help but it says I must set AUTHBIND=yes in the file location /etc/default/tomcat but for some reason this file is not present.

I have read previously that this file is not created if the installation was done from extracting the target file, this was my approach and this seems to me why the file is not there, I have no other solution.

Is there another way to set this authbind to yes or will I have to use Ip tables, or forward requests from Apache to tomcat. if i cant set authbind what in your opinion is the best solution.

Sorry if I left anything out, any help/suggestions would be of great help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just completely reinstall the Tomcat on to your system. I had a similar problem and this was the only solution for me.

Comment: Hi @javaninja, I didn't find a solution to the problem thank you for answering, considering nobody else contributed, I will accept tjis answer try to get you on your journey with stack overflow, enjoy the torture/journey...